# How to check if file exists in Google Cloud Storage using .NET and Google.Cloud.Storage.V1?

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I would like to check if the file exists before trying to delete it as I want to avoid the exception. Removal method below - **DeleteAssetAsync()**

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Cloud.Storage.V1;

internal sealed class AssetsService
{
    private readonly GoogleCredential _googleCredential;
    private readonly StorageClient _storageClient;

    public AssetsService()
    {
        _googleCredential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("google.json");
        _storageClient = StorageClient.Create(_googleCredential);
    }

    public async Task DeleteAssetAsync()
    {
        await _storageClient.DeleteObjectAsync("gcp-assets-bucket", "file.txt");
    }
}
```

Exception

> Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError No such object:
> gcp-assets-bucket/file.txt [404] Errors [
> Message[No such object: gcp-assets-bucket/file.txt] Location[ - ] Reason[notFound] Domain[global] ]
>
> The service storage has thrown an exception:
> Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError No such
> object: gcp-assets-bucket/file.txt [404] Errors [
> Message[No such object: gcp-assets-bucket/file.txt] Location[ - ] Reason[notFound] Domain[global] ]

I tried to download or get the file first and check if it is not null, but the downloading or getting method returns the same exception if it cannot find the file.

**GetObject** example

```
var googleAsset = await _storageClient.GetObjectAsync("gcp-assets-bucket", "file.txt");
if (googleAsset is not null)
{
    _storageClient.DeleteObjectAsync(googleAsset);
}
```

**DownloadObject** example

```
using var stream = File.OpenWrite("file.txt");
await _storageClient.DownloadObjectAsync("gcp-assets-bucket", "file.txt", stream);
```

Is there any way to check if file exists in Google Cloud Storage or get null if not exists without throwing an exception?

Comment: I think you can check if the object exists by getting the metadata. You may refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#storage-view-object-metadata-csharp) which shows you how to implement it using C#.

Comment: To not get a not found exception use **ListFilesWithPrefix**. Then check if the object is present. IIRC set the prefix to be your object name. That will return an empty list if the object is not present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same idea John Hanley mentioned.
Use ListObjects list to get the list of files with the same prefix (directory path). Then check if the object is present.

```
private bool FileExists(string bucketName, string fileName)
{
    var objects = _storageClient.ListObjects(bucketName, Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName)).ToArray();
    return objects.Any(x => x.Name == fileName);
}
```